# Alternative implement to download attribute of <a>

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

As the [example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download2) on W3schools shows,

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download="w3logo"></a>
```

works on chrome, the download filename is rename to "w3logo.jpg", but it seems that only works on static file. If i change the href to

```
<a href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery/jquery/master/LICENSE.txt" download="w3logo"></a>
```

which looks like a static file, the rename function failed to work.

And we also know that even with static file, it only works on a few explorers.

Is there any alternative solution for this, doing both download and rename? with a little js is fine, html only is better.

Answer (score 3):

The `download` attribute is still not fully supported by all browsers, and the ones that do support it do not always honor the default filename. This normally happens when the file to be downloaded is not from the [same origin](https://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) as the server the script is running on. For more info, check out the [HTML spec for the download attribute](https://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [the MDN page about Anchor tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), the download attribute is introduced in HTML5 and not supported properly by all the browsers. Here's the [caniuse link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download) for more info about support.

Even with the support enabled there're few limitations. The first one is if there's a [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header present in response headers, then it'll take priority over download attribute for file name.

Since Chrome prioritise the `download` attribute unlike Firefox, the second limitation comes into picture for your example which is the file url has to be from **same origin**. The url you mentioned is from different origin, thus the download attribute has no effect at all. This limitation is there in latest version of Chrome and Firefox both as far as I know.